# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMJIT(and -lLLVMipa) in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, llvm

I want to use the llvm framework to build a simple compiler like this

[A simple compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPcF7.png)

and implement the code in Ubuntu 16.04. But I got the error

```
[ 20%] Linking CXX executable driver
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMJIT
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMipa
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/driver.dir/build.make:219: recipe for target 'driver' failed
make[2]: *** [driver] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/driver.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/driver.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I search the LLVMJIT library in the command `apt-file search libLLVMJIT` and `apt-file search libLLVMipa` and got the following output

```
haoxin@ubuntu:~/github/dcc888$ apt-file search libLLVMJIT
libllvm-3.5-ocaml-dev: /usr/lib/ocaml/llvm-3.5/libLLVMJIT.a
llvm-3.5-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libLLVMJIT.a
haoxin@ubuntu:~/github/dcc888$ apt-file search libLLVMipa
libllvm-3.5-ocaml-dev: /usr/lib/ocaml/llvm-3.5/libLLVMipa.a
llvm-3.5-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libLLVMipa.a
llvm-3.6-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-3.6/lib/libLLVMipa.a
llvm-3.7-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/lib/libLLVMipa.a
```

these are static library that Maybe I cannot use in LLVM JIT.

When I use the command `make VERBOSE=1`, the output are follows:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 -B/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1/CMakeFiles /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1'
make -f CMakeFiles/driver.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/driver.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1'
cd /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1 /home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1/CMakeFiles/driver.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1'
make -f CMakeFiles/driver.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/driver.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1'
[ 20%] Linking CXX executable driver
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/driver.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions    CMakeFiles/driver.dir/Driver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/driver.dir/Expr.cpp.o CMakeFiles/driver.dir/Lexer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/driver.dir/Parser.cpp.o  -o driver -rdynamic -lLLVMJIT /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86Disassembler.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86AsmParser.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMSelectionDAG.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMAsmPrinter.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMMCParser.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMCodeGen.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMObjCARCOpts.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMInstCombine.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86Desc.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86Info.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86AsmPrinter.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMX86Utils.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.a -lLLVMipa /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMIRReader.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMBitReader.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMAsmParser.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMExecutionEngine.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMAnalysis.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMTarget.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMMC.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMObject.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMCore.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMSupport.a -lpthread -ltinfo -ldl /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMDebugInfoCodeView.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMDebugInfoMSF.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMMCDisassembler.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMGlobalISel.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMCodeGen.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMInstCombine.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMBitWriter.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMTarget.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMAnalysis.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMProfileData.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMObject.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMMCParser.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMBitReader.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMMC.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMCore.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.a /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMSupport.a -lz -lrt -ltinfo -ldl -lpthread -lm /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libLLVMDemangle.a 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMJIT
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMipa
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/driver.dir/build.make:219: recipe for target 'driver' failed
make[2]: *** [driver] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/driver.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/driver.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/haoxin/github/dcc888/dcc888-1'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMakeList.txt messages:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions( -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS )
add_definitions( -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS )
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
        Core
        ExecutionEngine
        Interpreter
        MC
        Support
        nativecodegen
        )


add_executable(driver Driver.cpp Expr.cpp Lexer.cpp Parser.cpp Expr.h Lexer.h Parser.h)

target_link_libraries(driver
        LLVMJIT
        LLVMRuntimeDyld
        LLVMX86Disassembler
        LLVMX86AsmParser
        LLVMX86CodeGen
        LLVMSelectionDAG
        LLVMAsmPrinter
        LLVMMCParser
        LLVMCodeGen
        LLVMObjCARCOpts
        LLVMScalarOpts
        LLVMInstCombine
        LLVMX86Desc
        LLVMX86Info
        LLVMX86AsmPrinter
        LLVMX86Utils
        LLVMTransformUtils
        LLVMipa
        LLVMIRReader
        LLVMBitReader
        LLVMAsmParser
        LLVMExecutionEngine
        LLVMAnalysis
        LLVMTarget
        LLVMMC
        LLVMObject
        LLVMCore
        LLVMSupport
        )

target_link_libraries(driver
        pthread
        tinfo
        dl
        )
```

I expect the `make` work out ok and `drive` can execute successfully.

Comment: What does the output look like if you do `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: hi, @Elias, the output message after `make VERBOSE=1` are follows:
sorry, the characters are out of range, I just updated my question details.

Answer (score 1):

There is much better llvm support in cmake if you target cmake 3.5, which will address a lot of these problems by adding the ability to reference libraries in virtual groups, rather than the manual list of libraries you're using.

You're using a list of libraries that would have been suitable in the llvm 3.5 timeframe, but you're linking against llvm 6, so several things have changed in the interim - a lot of library reorganization. For example, the [LLVMJIT library was removed](https://releases.llvm.org/3.6.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#the-old-jit-has-been-removed) in `3.6`, and LLVMipa was removed in 3.8 (no reference found in anything other than source code), but the long and short of this is that it's a delicate list of libraries that will change as you build against different versions of llvm.

you do a:

```
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
    Core
    ExecutionEngine
    Interpreter
    MC
    Support
    nativecodegen
    )
```

is supposed to deal with all the libraries that you're linking - you should not be adding a full list of libraries to link manually at the end like that.

Based on the list of libraries you need to add the following components:

```
mcjit
x86 (covers asmparser, disassembler and code generator)
asmparser
objcarcopts (LLVMObjCARCOpts - is it needed???)
scalaropts
transformutils
irreader
```

so changing to:

```
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
    Core
    ExecutionEngine
    Interpreter
    MC
    Support
    nativecodegen
    mcjit
    x86
    asmparser
    objcarcopts
    scalaropts
    transformutils
    irreader
    )
```

gives us the list of components to use. `LLVMipa` was rolled back into the main `LLVMAnalysis`, so you no longer need to specify it.

setting a variable for the libraries:

```
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs ${LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS})
```

This uses the llvm mapping code to map to the needed libraries.

Changing the link line to:

```
target_link_libraries(driver
        pthread
        tinfo
        dl
        ${llvm_libs}
        )
```

will link the relevant libraries, and you can remove the `target_link_libraries` specifying the individual libraries.

Comment: thanks, @Petesh. It works out ok. By the way, the `x86` could be replace in uppercase `X86`.

Comment: The module names are case insensitive, but the library names aren’t (if you’re using Linux)