# Linker can't find LLVM libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, clang

I am currently working on a C++ project involving the Clang library for code tokenization. After installing the Clang library using apt-get install, I proceeded to set up my project's CMakeLists.txt for building. However, I've run into linking issues that I am seeking assistance to resolve. I am in deep despair :'(

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMX86Utils
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVMipa
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/goodcommit.dir/build.make:97: goodcommit] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/goodcommit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(goodcommit)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) 

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")

set(LLVM_PATH /usr/lib/llvm-14)
link_directories(${LLVM_PATH}/lib)
include_directories(${LLVM_PATH}/include)

add_definitions(
-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
)

# Use llvm-config to get compilation flags
execute_process(
    COMMAND llvm-config --cxxflags
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_CXX_FLAGS
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

# Use llvm-config to get linking flags
execute_process(
    COMMAND llvm-config --ldflags
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_LD_FLAGS
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

# Set the compilation flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${LLVM_CXX_FLAGS}")

# Set the linking flags
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${LLVM_LD_FLAGS}")

set(SOURCE_FILE main.cpp)
add_executable(goodcommit ${SOURCE_FILE})

target_link_libraries(goodcommit
  clangFrontend
  clangSerialization
  clangDriver
  clangParse
  clangSema
  clangAnalysis
  clangAST
  clangBasic
  clangEdit
  clangLex
  clangTooling
  LLVMX86AsmParser
  LLVMX86Desc
  LLVMX86AsmPrinter
  LLVMX86Info
  LLVMX86Utils
  LLVMipo
  LLVMScalarOpts
  LLVMInstCombine
  LLVMTransformUtils
  LLVMipa
  LLVMAnalysis
  LLVMTarget
  LLVMOption
  LLVMMCParser
  LLVMMC
  LLVMObject
  LLVMBitReader
  LLVMCore
  LLVMSupport
  -lgit2
)
```

I have tried following the steps of building llvm project but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere! Plus my header

```
<clang-c/Index.h>
```

doesn't seem to be recognized.
Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: What does `llvm-config --ldflags` show if you run it from the command line?  Does it say `-L/some/path`? If so, if you look in that path (or those paths if there are more than one), do you find the missing libraries?

Comment: LLVMipa [seems to have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727636/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lllvmjitand-lllvmipa-in-ubuntu-16-04). Are you sure about all those libraries?

Comment: Setting a **compiler** after the `project` call is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your answer.Yes i can find the missing libraries. I am able to build my project just fine, but the types CXIndex, CXTranslationUnit and CXCursor are written white which means they aren't recognized by my editor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo here are my changes of CMakeLists.txt so the compiler can look into the right directory ; ` 
include_directories("/usr/lib/llvm-14/include") ` and ` 
# Include Clang headers
target_include_directories(goodcommit PUBLIC ${LLVM_CLANG_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(goodcommit /home/nora/Téléchargements/llvm-project/build/lib/libclang.so -lgit2) ` but i still get my headers pointing at /usr/include/clang which doesn't contain any of the wanted headers. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Do you mean it now compiles and links properly but the IDE is showing some errors?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I havn't expressed myself well.  I am able to build my project and when i compile my source code, ` 
void tokenizeCode() {
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
    index,
    "file1.txt", nullptr, 0,
    nullptr, 0,
    CXTranslationUnit_None);
    if (unit == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to parse translation unit. Quitting." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }etc.` it jumps to Unable to parse translation unit because CXTranslationUnit isn't recognized (written in white, plus i don't get suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved the problem;
Since my include headers in my source code were pointing at /usr/include/clang but were actually in /usr/lib/llvm-14/include/, I created a directory named "clang-c" in /usr/include/clang/14/include and created a symbolic link to the clang-c directory that had the headers. And it resolved the problem :)